# Using numpy to find the number of non-zero values in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I often need to find the number of values satisfying some condition for a large 1D array of values.  Through a little trial and error I ended up with the following method:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random_sample(500000)  # just some trial data

num_above_half = len(np.nonzero(a > 0.5)[0])
```

an equivalent method:

```
num_above_half = sum(a > 0.5)
```

is almost 300 X slower on my machine.   The first method is fine, but the syntax is a little messy, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Benchmarking the different equivalent ways to count a certain condition shows that `np.count_nonzero` is the fastest.

```
In [2]: %timeit len(np.nonzero(a > 0.5)[0])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.24 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit sum(a > 0.5)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.23 s per loop

In [4]: %timeit (a > 0.5).sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 906 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(a > 0.5)
1000 loops, best of 3: 266 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't benchmarked anything, but what about [`np.count_nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html)?

Comment: @mgilson: `np.count_nonzero` is the winner for speed (5X speed-up v. `len()` method), this is detailed in post linked by DSM.  Probably can close as dup as DSM suggests.

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah, I think it counts :-)